# Web API not calling, if parameter consist @ character

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have an API, which is structured by three params (param1,param2,param3). for email parameter its not working, because '@' character. but normally working fine. please check my below code.

**API Controller**

```
public class ApiPINVerificationController : ApiController
{
    public ApiPINVerificationController()
    {

    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult GetStudentByPIN(string param1,string param2,string param3)
    {
        //Balance Search Audit Log Entry
        SLAF.DataAccessManager.DTO.BalanceSearchLog balanceSearchLog = new DataAccessManager.DTO.BalanceSearchLog
        {
            PIN=param1,
            CellPhone=param2,
            Email=param3
        };
        APIManager.InsertBalanceSearchLog(balanceSearchLog);
        return Ok(new
        {
            Student=objStudent
        });
    }
}
```

**WebApiConfig**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static string UrlPrefixRelative { get { return "~/Api"; } }
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        //config.Formatters.Add(new BsonMediaTypeFormatter());
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{param}",
            defaults: new { param = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Api2",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{param1}/{param2}"
        );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Api3",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{param1}/{param2}/{param3}"
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot receive parameters like this,, You could use json parameters or body content parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the @ character isn't your problem. I see that the email is the last parameter and as it most likely ends in .com or something else, the URL doesn't work.

Try to add a trailing `/` character and you'll see that the API calls succeed.

```
https://youraddress.com/api/something/something/param1/param2/email@something.com/
```

Comment: @sebu Good to hear, feel free to mark it as answered if it fixes your problem. :)